# Can sed execute a command on empty file (quit command)

Tags: shell-script, sed, exit-status

I have a shell script in which I want to validate the content of a file.

The expected content should have a specific first line, say `^MYFIRSTROW`, **and** not be empty.

So I wrote this check using GNU `sed` :

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# "1q1": return 1 on input line 1. Only reached if the pattern did not match.
if sed -rn '/^MYFIRSTROW/q0; 1q1' myfile; then
   # ...
fi
```

but I tested on an empty input, and `sed` then returns 0 instead of 1:

```
echo -ne '' | sed -rn '/^MYFIRSTROW/q0; 1q1'; echo $?
# 0
```

Also, I did not find a way to use the address '0' in this case.

Is there a way to make it in one command in GNU sed?

##### NOTE: alternative solutions

I would primarily like to answer if executing sed commands on empty input is possible and how, but elegant suggestions for my shell script are welcome:

- I'm slow but I just realized that `if [ -s "myfile" ] && sed ...` does the job.
- I can imagine a solution using `while read < myfile` but seems cumbersome.
- I have the opposite problem in `awk`, where the END block is always executed, so that this code always returns 1:

  ```
  awk 'NR==1 && /^MYPATTERN/ {exit 0}END{exit 1}' myfile
  ```

P.S: sorry, my question might look too much like a code golf request, but I just wanted a concise and efficient file content checking in my script.

Answer (score 1):

The primary answer is: No. `sed` executes its script for each line, so if there is no line, no command can get executed.

The workaround: let your shell add one line one the fly:

```
sed -n '/^MYPATTERN/q;$q1;2q2' <(echo) yourfile
```

The `<(echo)` pretents to be a file with one empty line, so `sed` will always execute it's script. If `yourfile` is empty, the first line is also the last, so `$q1` will exit with status 1.

Otherwise the script will get executed on the first line of `yourfile`. If it matches, exit with status code 0.

If it doesn't match, `sed` exists with status 2. Note that the added line makes the first line of the file appear as line 2 to `sed`.

Thank you Stéphane Chazelas for the hint how to achieve the same thing for shells without support for ksh-style process substitution:

```
echo|sed -n '/^MYPATTERN/q;$q1;2q2' - yourfile
```

The `-` as argument stands for stdin, which is the empty line piped from `echo`.

Comment: Or for shells without support for ksh-style process substitution: `echo|sed -n '/^MYPATTERN/q;$q1;2q2' - yourfile`

Answer (score 0):

With AWK, you could set a variable that tells the `END` block which exit code to set. Here, abusing the fact that `ok` will be zeroish if not explicitly assigned. (Alternatively, add `BEGIN { ok=0 }` to be explicit.)

```
awk 'NR==1 && /^MYPATTERN/ {ok=1; exit} NR==2 {exit} END {exit !ok}' myfile
```

That's a bit explicit on purpose, and could well be golfed esp. since we're only looking for the pattern on the first line.

---

I'm not sure how to do that in sed in a straightforward manner. Though you could do it inverted, exiting with a one if `MYPATTERN` is seen, and relying on it exiting with zero on an empty file. Then you need to invert the sense of the surrounding `if`:

```
if ! sed -Ene '/^MYPATTERN/q1; 1q0' myfile; then
    echo "MYPATTERN seen..."
fi
```

Though that would go to the main branch of the `if` (and print `MYPATTERN seen...`) even if sed returned an actual error, like not being able to read `myfile`.

Comment: Or `awk '{found = /^MYPATTERN/; exit}; END {exit !found}'`